# Touch screen bug (using to display system screen)

Tags: display, touchscreen, screen, lcd

I'm trying to display my raspberry screen on a LCD touch screen.
I followed [http://www.lcdwiki.com/3.5inch_RPi_Display#Driver_Installation\](http://www.lcdwiki.com/3.5inch_RPi_Display#Driver_Installation%5C)
On this link there is a video showing it working properly, but when I try to use it on my raspberry I get some bugs.

For instance I can't open the raspberry menu on the taskbar (I click on it or press the keyboard shortcut and nothing happens)

When I try to execute a .sh file it should appear a window asking me how I wanna open
the file, this window is "invisible". I can click where the "execute on terminal" should be and it would execute.

[image]

Same goes for when I try to open a webpage. It's "invisible" but I can click on where the X button was supposed to be and close it.
[image]

Edit: The red square is what is supposed to be the web browser. I can click on it or drag it, but I cant see anything on it.
[image]

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: I wanna know how I could fix it, to make these windows visible. I cant see them, just their shades.
I uploaded a new photo so it's more clear now. Thats my "invisible" web browser window. I can drag it and move it around but I cant see anything on it.